# unable to set cacheing to false using jQuery.ajax

Tags: jquery, html, heroku

i'm trying to use the quotesondesign api to get random quotes.  i've tried setting $ajax cache to false when the document is ready and in the http request function with no luck.  Now the api always returns the same quote.  Could it possibly be the cors-anywhere heroku endpoint?  Any idea how I can go about fixing this?

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajaxSetup({ 
        cache: false 
      });
    $('#getNewQuote').on("click", getQuote);

    function getQuote() {
        timeStamp = new Date();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=randfilter[posts_per_page]=1timestamp=' + timeStamp,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(a) {
                console.log(a);                 
                    $("#quoteContent").html(a[0].content);              
                    $("#quoteAuthor").html(a[0].title);
            }
                });             
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is incorrectly formatted. change it to:

```
url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&timestamp=' + timeStamp,
```

You are missing ampersands, sop the endpoint is not understanding your query.

See https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1 with the fixed query, and you'll see what you expect - one random quote.